# python manage.py shell < scripts/myscript.py not working when the file contains if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a script(myscript.py) using
`python manage.py shell < scripts/myscript.py`
but nothing happens.

Here is my code

**myscript.py**

```
def foo(x):
    print(x+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 10
    foo(x)
```

any help please

Note:

I am new to django

I am using python 3.6 and django 1.10.6

Comment: Make your script print out `__name__` and you will see why.

Comment: What output and error messages do you get?

Comment: @RedCricket
there is no error messages. it looks like `__name__` is not `'__main__'`
Output:
```Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... >>> >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
now exiting InteractiveConsole...```

Comment: @KlausD.
ok thank you. I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are importing that script into shell, value of variable `__name__` will not be `__main__` (it will be the module name `myscript`). That means here that part of code is not executing.

For more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: thank you for the help
so it means that i should not use `if __name__ == '__main__'`?
or can I change `'__main__'` into my module name? for example:
 `if __name__ == 'myscript'`

Comment: I you need to import the function, remove that line and call function directly in the shell after import